# Python PyQt5 убрать кнопку Развернуть/Свернуть

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Есть окно на `PyQt5`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setFixedSize(200, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Как убрать ненужный пункт меню Развернуть/Свернуть?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Qt для различных виджетов и диалоговых окон можно задавать WindowsFlags, меняющие их отображение. Чтобы сделать что-то нестандартное, нужно объявить наш виджет custom'ным, для этого используется флаг **Qt::CustomizeWindowHint**, Например, следующий код показывает только кнопку закрытия у диалогового окна в Qt (C++):

```
QDialog d;
d.setWindowFlags( Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint );
d.setWindowTitle("abcd");
d.show();
```

[image: Результат]

Подробнее:

- [официальный пример работы с флагами Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-windowflags-example.html)
- [перечень Qt::WindowsFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum)

Comment: А каким образом оставить только кнопку закрытия и сворачивания? Не могу разобраться.

Comment: Пробую так: `setWindowFlags(Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)`, но получаю все три кнопки, просто кнопка разворачивания не рабочая. Просто серая, как на скрине в посте.

Comment: @dtcobra, В официальной документации есть приписка к **Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint**: "_Adds a minimize button. On some platforms this implies Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint for it to work._", а **Qt::WindowSystemMenuHint** показывает обе кнопки. Похоже, что используемый встроенный оконный менеджер просто не позволяет сделать то, что ты хочешь.

Comment: Принудительное отрицание флага кнопки maximize тоже не помогает в windows 10. `setWindowFlags( (Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint) & ~Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint)`;

Comment: Очень жаль. Ну спасибо, в любом случае