# Как скрыть кнопку "Развернуть" у диалогового окна Qt

Tags: python, c++, qt

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
this->setWindowFlags((this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowMaximizeButtonHint) | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint);
```

Но результат такой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как полностью скрыть кнопку "Развернуть", а не только деактивировать?

Answer (score 0):

А вот почти дубликат есть - [Python PyQt5 убрать кнопку Развернуть/Свернуть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/708596/python-pyqt5-%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C)

правда там по питону вопрос.

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint );
```

хотя мне кажется, для этого окна кнопка минимизировать не нужна, и соответствено лучше подойдет такое

```
this->setWindowFlags(Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint );
```

Comment: Я видел этот вопрос на питоне, там человек пришёл к выводу в комментариях, что это не сделать)

Comment: просто с кнопкой закрыть (второй вариант) у меня получился. С первый я поигрался, но не хочет оно так. Из того, что я знаю, предлагают просто сделать свой заголовок окна:)